# How to properly update configset in SolrCloud mode

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr4

I referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55158976/changes-to-solrconfig-xml-are-not-reflected-in-solrcloud) to edit my solrconfig.xml file, though the changes are reflected in solrconfig.xml in zookeeper the `/spell` request handler that I commented is still working. Following are the steps that I followed

1. First I created a collection with collection name **amazon_products** with `_default` configset and in zookeeper, configset with name same as collection name **amazon_products** is created as shown below

[image]

2. Then I downloaded configset **amazon_products** and edited solrconfig.xml(commented `/spell` request handler) and then I uploaded the same to zookeper as shown below

[image]

3. Then I restarted solr using the following commands

   `bin/solr restart -c -p 8983 -s example/cloud/node1/solr`

   `bin/solr restart -c -p 7574 -z localhost:9983 -s example/cloud/node2/solr`
4. Now I used Solr Admin UI and changed request handler from `/select` to `/spell`, even though I commented request handler `/spell` in solrconfig.xml and uploaded that to zeekeeper and restarted the solr still queries executed with `/spell` request handler are working, but it should have shown 404 error for `/spell` as I commented this part
5. Just to verify whether changes to solrconfig.xml in zookeeper are reflected or not I downloaded configset and checked the **solconfig.xml** file the changes that I made were reflected properly

So to conclude though my changes are reflected why it is not working as excepted?

Is it a proper way to update configset in solrcloud?
Am I restarting solr properly?

**EDIT: I even tried reloading the collection instead of restarting collection but still having the same problem**

Reload command used:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=RELOAD&name=amazon_products
```

Comment: you need to upload the modified config set to zookeeper and then reload the collection

Comment: I did that, check 2nd point in my question

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem. I was giving wrong port number for zookeeper so changing port number from 2181 to 9983 solved the problem.

changed the command from

```
bin/solr zk upconfig -n amazon_products -d /Users/swastikn/Documents/solr_configs/my_sample_configs -z localhost:2181
```

to

```
bin/solr zk upconfig -n amazon_products -d /Users/swastikn/Documents/solr_configs/my_sample_configs -z localhost:9983
```